# NoClassDefFoundError in Geotools QueryLab.java tutorial

Tags: geotools

When running the file given by geotools in https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/filter/query.html

I get the error:
[image: org/geotools/gml/SubHandlerLinearRing]

NoClassDefFoundError
org/geotools/gml/SubHandlerLinearRing

Any idea why this is? This is my pom.xml

```xml
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.openhm</groupId>
    <artifactId>openhm</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>openhm</name>
    
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <geotools.version>28-SNAPSHOT</geotools.version>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <jakartaee>8.0</jakartaee>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jakartaee}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
         <!-- Provides map projections -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-epsg-hsql</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Provides support for PostGIS. Note the different groupId -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-jdbc-postgis</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Provides support for shapefiles -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-shapefile</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Provides GUI components -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-swing</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
    <repositories>
       <repository>
         <id>osgeo</id>
         <name>OSGeo Release Repository</name>
         <url>https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/release/</url>
         <snapshots><enabled>false</enabled></snapshots>
         <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
       </repository>
       <repository>
         <id>osgeo-snapshot</id>
         <name>OSGeo Snapshot Repository</name>
         <url>https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/snapshot/</url>
         <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
         <releases><enabled>false</enabled></releases>
       </repository>
     </repositories>

     <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>${jakartaee}</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

When attempting to import said missing class, there is no Maven repository available for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That class can be found in the `gt-xml` module, which isn't a dependency of the Query tutorial as it doesn't handle XML files.

So you need to add it as a dependency if you need it.